# Kentico 9 - Separate MVC Application - Document Attachment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

I am trying to add an attachment to a document - I am running a separate MVC application - not part of the same solution as the Kentico admin site.

I am getting error site not found for my `UserInfo`.

```
public Models.PartnerUpdateModel NewPartnerUpdate(Models.PartnerUpdateModel partnerupdatemodel)
{
    CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode newpartnerupdatetreenode = CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.New(partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.ClassName);
    TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider();
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.Title = partnerupdatemodel.Title;
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.Summary = partnerupdatemodel.Summary;
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.Article = partnerupdatemodel.Article;
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.Author = partnerupdatemodel.MarketConnectUser.UserID.ToString();
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.DocumentCulture = partnerupdatemodel.DocumentCulture;
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.Insert(TreeHelper.SelectSingleNode(partnerupdatemodel.MarketConnectUser.DefaultGroup.GroupChildNodes.Where(x => x.Key == partnerupdatemodel.ParentClassName).Select(x => x.Value).Single()), true);
    partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.SubmitChanges(true);
    foreach (var file in partnerupdatemodel.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile postedfile = FileHelper.ConstructHttpPostedFile(FileHelper.ToByteArray(file.InputStream), file.FileName, file.ContentType);              
        DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(newpartnerupdatetreenode, Models.PartnerUpdateModel.AttachmentColumnNames.Image.ToString(), postedfile, new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser)); //GETTING ERROR HERE
        newpartnerupdatetreenode.Update();
    }
    return partnerupdatemodel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MembershipContext is not oficially supported in v9 ([Supported and unsupported Kentico features on MVC sites](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Supported+and+unsupported+Kentico+features+on+MVC+sites)) however I think this should work - to be honest I have tried it by myself and I`ve got UserInfo (for public user and global admin too). Could you please provide call stack of exception?

edit: I have also tried to get current SiteInfo like

```
var site = SiteContext.CurrentSite;
```

and it`s null if you have not specified Presentation URL - could you check this setting?

Comment: It was not set and it was null. I fixed this and now the site shows up for SiteContext.CurrentSite. However my user site is null.

Comment: What about call stack?

Comment: It no longer throws errors, but the attachment is not saved. Using  TreeNode node = TreeHelper.SelectSingleDocument(partnerupdatemodel.KenticoPartnerUpdate.DocumentID);
                    //node.Attachments.Add()

                    //AttachmentInfoProvider.SetAttachmentInfo(info);
               
                    DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(node, "Image", postedfile, new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser));
                    node.Update();

Comment: I found that in the db the CMS_Attachment table SiteID column was null.  Setting the SiteID column allows the attachments to show up in the admin.

Comment: I think this issue happened because I am not using Kentico Membership or Kentico Authentication.  Instead I created a custom IPrinciple.  This is likely why the user userinfo does not contain a site.  To solve this I created an after insert trigger on the CMS_Attachment table.  I think another solution would be to authenticate the user with the Kentico API.

Comment: Yeas, I am authenticating user via membership module - AuthenticationHelper - and everything works like a charm